# Webpack not re-exporting values

Tags: javascript, webpack

New to working with Webpack directly, and I'm having trouble getting it to include imported code into the bundle. For a test, I have two files.

index.js:

```
export const stringFromIndex = 'string-abc';

export { somestring } from './testModule.js'
```

testModule.js:

```
export const someString = 'string-123';
```

When I run webpack, 'string-abc' is in the created bundle, but 'string-123' is not. My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

require ('script-loader');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'output.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    },
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'script-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I configuring webpack wrong, or am I misunderstanding what goes into the bundle? In the cases where I use something that uses webpack (Vue CLI primarily), without chunking/lazy loading, everything goes into the created JS file. That's what I'm trying to achieve here.

The output of the webpack run is:

```
Hash: 6e6474a0bc8438c6fdd8
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 83ms
Built at: 03/07/2020 12:25:02 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
output.js  5.71 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = output.js
[./index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/script-loader/node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./index.js] ./node_modules/script-loader/node_modules/raw-loader!./index.js 115 bytes {main} [built]
    + 1 hidden module
```

I have a Gist at: https://gist.github.com/emamid/5c369a8001d9d8cace3811b04da7b2ff

Comment: You have someString in your testModule.js but you import somestring (no camelCase). Can you try using the same name in both places?

Comment: Fixed that, but but still no "string-123" in output.js after re-running webpack.

Comment: Why are you using script-loader?

Comment: Because I was a newbie to webpack, and thought that every file needed a loader type. Removing script-loader makes it work perfectly. Thanks!